# Sort array of dictionaries where key is unknown

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries of type `[[String:SchoolModel]]`. The keys are the id of the school and then the school model contains info about the school like its name for example. I want to sort this array by SchoolModel.name, but can't figure out how since my key is a unique id for every element in the array.

```
struct SchoolModel {
   var name: String
   var city: String
   var state: String
}
```

Comment: So each `Dictionary` in your `Array` only contains a single key-value pair? Why not use a single `Dictionary` then? Or `DictionaryLiteral` if you need the ordering.

Comment: Do provide a sample of this array

Comment: Why isn't the key which is the id, part of your model? But still, you can do `let sorted = array.sorted(by: { return Array($0.values).first!.name < Array($1.values).first!.name })` (badly done with force unwrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the first value of each dictionary iterated to get the name.

```
struct SchoolModel {
    var name: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
}

let schools: [[String:SchoolModel]] = [
    ["1": SchoolModel(name: "1", city: "a", state: "x")],
    ["2": SchoolModel(name: "2", city: "b", state: "y")],
    ["3": SchoolModel(name: "3", city: "c", state: "z")]
]

print(schools.sorted {
    guard
        let a = $0.values.first?.name,
        let b = $1.values.first?.name else { return false }

    return a < b
})
```

However, you should consider adding an `id` property to your struct. You can make it optional so you can still initiate a `SchoolModel` that hasn't been created yet.

```
struct SchoolModel {
    var id: String?
    var name: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
}
```

Then where ever you are populating the array of dictionaries, append the `SchoolModel` object without embedding it inside a dictionary, resulting in an array of type `[SchoolModel]`.

Comment: The reason I have it as a dictionary was because I am storing the ids in my database as keys for something else. But as I start to type this out I realize that you my thinking was wrong and you are very correct. Thank you